# Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM while sending transaction via ropsten infura testnet

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, web3js

I have a smart contract which is deployed via remix IDE on the ropsten testnet:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract PrinterMarketplace {
    uint256 public requestCount = 0;
    uint256 public offerCount = 0;
    uint256 public orderCount = 0;

    mapping(uint256 => Request) public requests;
    struct Request {
        uint256 id;
        address payable client;
        string fileHash;
    }
    mapping(uint256 => Offer) public offers;
    struct Offer {
        uint256 id;
        uint256 price;
        string fileHash;
        address payable client;
        address payable provider;
        bool purchased;
    }
    mapping(uint256 => Order) public orders;
    struct Order {
        uint256 id;
        uint256 price;
        address payable client;
        address payable provider;
        bool purchased;
        string fileHash;

    }

    function setRequest(string memory _fileHash) public {
        requestCount++;
        requests[requestCount] = Request(requestCount, msg.sender, _fileHash);
    }

    function setOffer(uint256 _offerPrice, string memory _fileHash, address payable _client, address payable _provider) public {
        offerCount++;
        offers[offerCount] = Offer(
            offerCount,
            _offerPrice,
            _fileHash,
            _client,
            _provider,
            false
        );
    }

    /*     function get() public view returns (string memory) {
        return fileHash;
    } */

    function purchaseOffer(
        uint256 _id,
        uint256 _orderPrice,
        address payable _client,
        address payable _provider,
        string memory _fileHash
    ) public payable {
        orderCount++;
        //fetch the offer
        // Order memory _order = Order(_id, _orderPrice, _owner, true);
        orders[orderCount] = Order(_id, _orderPrice, _client, _provider, true, _fileHash);
        //pay the seller by sendding them ether
        address(uint160(_provider)).transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

While running my javascript code, I get the following error:

```
Error in setOffer:  { Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x71561626c29b157c9e01b6cb143868055a570ce99a4fa0d4a1f4a827ec401ee4",
  "blockNumber": 8562752,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 1602671,
  "from": "0x2692dea243c0341a48ba9017e84d5bc4ab1d2e0d",
  "gasUsed": 23267,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x8285ed4dbfba6faa5bd9da628579239168dd2e06",
  "transactionHash": "0x4fe04293fbce89472bb8508598fc1598794f1ab20788c234eac1d32fbd9cdcf4",
  "transactionIndex": 4
}
    at Object.TransactionError (/home/emre/CARDAMOM/PrinterApp/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:93:21)
    at Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError (/home/emre/CARDAMOM/PrinterApp/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:105:21)
    at /home/emre/CARDAMOM/PrinterApp/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:474:48
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  receipt:
   { blockHash:
      '0x71561626c29b157c9e01b6cb143868055a570ce99a4fa0d4a1f4a827ec401ee4',
     blockNumber: 8562752,
     contractAddress: null,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 1602671,
     from: '0x2692dea243c0341a48ba9017e84d5bc4ab1d2e0d',
     gasUsed: 23267,
     logs: [],
     logsBloom:
      '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
     status: false,
     to: '0x8285ed4dbfba6faa5bd9da628579239168dd2e06',
     transactionHash:
      '0x4fe04293fbce89472bb8508598fc1598794f1ab20788c234eac1d32fbd9cdcf4',
     transactionIndex: 4 } }
```

I see on etherscan the transaction but it is marked with failed.

Here is my js code:

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;
var privateKey = new Buffer('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'hex')

async function writeOfferToContract(_offerprice, _fileHash, _contract, _client, _account) {
    var data = await _contract.methods.setOffer(_offerprice, _fileHash, _client, _account).encodeABI();
    var nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(_account);
    nonce = '0x' + nonce.toString(16)

    var rawTx = {
        nonce: nonce, //web3.eth.getTransactionCount(_account) + 1,
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex('10000000000'),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex('3000000'),
        to: '0x8285ed4dbfba6faa5bd9da628579239168dd2e06',
        from: '0x2692DEA243c0341A48ba9017e84d5BC4Ab1D2E0d',
        value: web3.utils.toHex(_offerprice),
        data: data,
        chainId: 3 //ropsten = 3
    }

    var tx = new Tx(rawTx, { 'chain': 'ropsten' });
    tx.sign(privateKey);

    var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

    if (_offerprice != 'undefined' && _contract != 'undefined') {
        try {

            const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function (err, hash) {
                if (!err)
                    console.log('ERROR:', hash); 
            });
            console.log(receipt)
            console.log('OFFER SUCCESSFULLY WRITTEN IN CONTRACT')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error in setOffer: ', error)
        }
    }
    //console.log('offerPrice: ', _contract.methods.getOfferPrice()) test
}
module.exports = {
    writeOfferToContract
};
```

For me everything looks proper and I really dont know where to continue in this case.
Can someone help me to find the problem. Maybe the error has something to do with the contractAddress: null in the reponse, I dont know..

I have attached the etherscan transaction [image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing gas limit?

Comment: I tried it and now I am getting Error: Returned error: exceeds block gas limit

Comment: I have changed gaslimit to 210.000. There is no problem with the gaslimit. I am still getting the same error mentioned in the Header. This error is very abstract for me and not addressing the actual problem...Any ideas how to eliminate potential mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

I have removed  from: '0x2692DEA243c0341A48ba9017e84d5BC4Ab1D2E0d' and chainId: 3.
Then I set value to '0'.

It's properly working now.

Comment: Hi, @Emre how is it supposed to work without from address?